# How is boolean xx = (43.3L == 3.333f) syntactically correct

Tags: java, boolean, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I'm have a problem with understanding this question about syntax it says the answer is

`boolean xx = (43.3L == 3.333f);`

but i don't understand how it is

Which of the following Java statements are NOT syntactically correct?

```
boolean x = (0.600 == 3.3d);
boolean bw = (false == true);
double dd = 2.5d;
boolean xx = (43.3L == 3.333f);
String\[\] se =new String\[6\];
```

Comment: Questions in your title and description do not match.

Comment: `43.3` is not a valid `long` value.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Derived from "*Which of the following **Java** statements are NOT syntactically correct?*" in the question body.

Comment: @PM77-1 - Well-derived. :-)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `boolean xx = (43.3L == 3.333f)` isn't correct and the IDE refuses it.

With `43.3L` you ask to consider a decimal number (=> a `float` or `double` in *Java*) as a `long` (the `L`).

If you remove the `L` the expression will evaluate.

The three others evaluate.

[image]

Comment: Sorry - did not see that you added it.